# How do I get my Creative X-Fi USB HD working consistently? (now random)

Tags: sound, alsa, sound-blaster

I have a sound card [Creative Soundblaster X-Fi HD (USB)](http://us.store.creative.com/Creative-Sound-Blaster-XFi-HD-Sound/M/B004275EO4.htm) which works perfectly in Windows 7. However, it doesn't work well on Ubuntu 12.10. Whenever I switch on my computer it boots in any of these three states:

- The sound card is not "fully" recognized (it shows that it is connected but I cannot get in the level-meter using `alsamixer` in the terminal).
- The soundblaster is fully recognized, I have access at all parameters, but it emits no sound.
- It works perfectly (about one out of five times).

I checked the others topics, it seems that nobody has found a solution so far...

What kind of command could I tip in order to "see" the difference between these three cases? I guess the problem comes from the "initialization" of the sound card, but I notice no change in the configuration/alsamixer between the second and the third case.

How can I make sure it is initialized correctly and working all the time? Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! *I checked the others topics, but nothing works so far.* Could you elaborate a bit more on this? Please edit your question with your actual attempts and results of it. It would be sad if answers come in you've already tried without success.

Comment: Show the output of the [alsa-info.sh](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh) script in all three cases.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. 
today I couldn't "make" the first case appear, so let's say that it doesn't happen often enough to focus on it.

Regarding both other cases: the files created by the alsa-info.sh are far too big to be copy/paste here, but they look totally similar (I compared them line by line). which part are you interested in so I could copy-paste only this?